# zend framework2 + doctrine 2, add time to table

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need help. So, i would like add row with time typ. I have following code.
Entity maper xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping>
    <entity name="Entity\Facility" table="facility">
        <id name="_id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
        <field name="_time_open" column="time_open" type="time"/>
        <field name="_time_close" column="time_close" type="time"/>

    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

This is my class:

```
class Facility extends AbstractEntity {
    private $_time_open;
    private $_time_close;

    public function setTimeOpen($timeOpen) {
        $this->_time_open = $timeOpen;
        return $this;
    }
    public function setTimeClose($timeClose) {
        $this->_time_close = $timeClose;
        return $this;
    }

    public function  getTimeOpen() {
        return $this->_time_open;
    }
    public function  getTimeClose() {
        return $this->_time_close;
    }

}
```

How can i add row with time type??
I tried in this way:

```
$facility->setTimeOpen(new DataTime()->format('h:i:s');
```

Comment: What error you got? What about `$facility->setTimeOpen(new DataTime())`?

Comment: How can set dateTime from varibles??

Comment: From varibles? What do you mean? Sth. like this: `$dataTime = new DataTime(); $facility->setTimeOpen($dataTime);` ?

Comment: nope:-( I solve my problem, thanks for all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as in comment. Please try to set just `DataTime` object, like:

```
$facility->setTimeOpen(new DataTime());
```

More in [doc](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#time).

Comment: How can set dateTime object from varibles??

for exampele:

    //string
    $time = '20:00:01'

I would like set this varibles object DateTime()